# Find time complexity of the recursive program

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

Can anyone please help me understand (step by step) on how to find the running time complexity of the below program?

```
   int memo[101][101];
int findMinPath(vector<vector<int> >& V, int r, int c) {
  int R = V.size();
  int C = V[0].size();
  if (r >= R || c >= C) return 100000000; // Infinity
  if (r == R - 1 && c == C - 1) return 0;
  if (memo[r][c] != -1) return memo[r][c];
  memo[r][c] =  V[r][c] + min(findMinPath(V, r + 1, c), findMinPath(V, r, c    + 1));
  return memo[r][c];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This process grows expotencially with the input, when input is: 'size - r'; every time findMinPath is called input is decreased by 1, and eventually rich zero and terminates.